# Github Sub-branches or Children of Branches?

Tags: github, branch

I am new to source control and am still touching up on all the features Github offers.

I have an app that works on mobile devices, and the entire project is on a repository with a single branch containing the entire project. I want to also support some other platforms (AR and VR), but I don't want any of the SDK's needed to run these in the mobile version as it would increase the file size of the app significantly.

Ideally, I would like to know the best way to use Github to take my main branch with the entire app for mobile, and create 2 sub-branches for AR and VR. These sub-branches would ideally be able to:

- Receive any updates that the main (mobile) branch gets automatically. This way each branch has the same 'game' and the only differences are the platform-specific SDK's that are needed to build it to a specific platform.
- Prevent updates to the main (mobile) branch in the case of an update to an SDK or other feature unrelated to the main branch.

I understand the concepts of pull/push/merge, but I wanted to know if there were any additional features that Github offers that make the process I want to do easier. I also want to ensure that if I push updates from the main branch to sub-branches, none of the platform specific SDK's are removed because they won't be present in the branch I am modifying.

Let me know if I am on the right track or if I missed something when researching Github's features. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a "sub-branch" does not really exist in Git. A branch must contain all of the files in a repo (unless you're deleting/creating them in that branch.) However, the problem you're trying to solve is a pretty common one -- the monorepo pattern seems like it would help here.

The idea is that you have a folder for each project within your repo, and you can also have a folder for any shared code. So in your case, you could have a folder for mobile, a folder for AR, a folder for VR, and a folder for the shared game code.

In this way, you can update the components separately while still keeping them in the same repo -- if the VR SDK needs an update, you can branch off of `main`, update the VR files that are strictly in the VR folder, and then merge that branch into main. This would leave the other folders untouched.

If this approach doesn't provide strict enough separation for your purposes, it would probably be a good idea to just create a separate repo for mobile, VR, AR, and the game code. Then, you can have the different implementations of the game `git clone` the game repo as part of their build process.

Generally speaking, the logic you're looking for of "if the game is updated, rebuild these sub-projects" is something you're going to need an automated pipeline for (or even just GitHub Actions), and git will just be the trigger for that pipeline. Git itself is not a build tool.

Comment: I had not heard of 'monorepo', but it seems like a better idea than my own. I will look into it more, thank you for the response!